# Pass object pointer via char[] to callback

Tags: c++

I have this function callback that receives a param of type T. T has a member function, GetData(), defined as below, which returns data to be used within the callback:

```
void Callback(T* t) {
    int64_t val;
    auto data = t->GetData();
    memcpy(&val, data, 8);
    std::cout << "Value: " << val;
}

// Member of a class T: 
char mData[64];

// Member functions of T
const char* GetData() const { return mData; }

void SetData(void* data, uint8_t size) { 
    if (size > 0) {
        memcpy(mData, data, size);
    }
}
```

The above works fine. However, for some reason, I can't seem to pass a 'this' pointer of a class within the data component. This is how the data is copied to the mData member.

```
// This works
char data[64];
int64_t val = 42;
memcpy(&data, &val, 8);
t->SetData(data, 8);

// For storing 'this', I tried variations of the below.
char data[64];
memcpy(&data, this, 8);
t->SetData(data, 8);
// t->SetData(this, 8);
```

When I try to store 'this' in the data, and then try to get it back in the callback, I can't seem to get the this pointer's value correctly. I tried variations of the below, including reinterpret_cast and others.

```
void Callback(T* t) {
  TypeOfThis* self;
  auto data = t->GetData();
  memcpy(&self, data, 8);
  // self has bogus values.
}
```

How can I pass a 'this' pointer correctly, in the case above?

Comment: Why your setData function is const if it is trying to change member variable mData

Comment: You are not copying the address stored in `this` - you are copying first 8 bytes of the class data that `this` points to. You need something like `TypeOfThis* self = this; memcpy(&data, &self, sizeof(self));`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: That worked!

Comment: @Kapil: Copypasta error. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

firstly "this" is to be used inside a class. 2ndly: "this" address does not necessarily point to the first data member of the class as there are some admin data subject to the compiler implementation, in other words there may be a few bytes gap between "this" and its first data member.